# Join between Polars dataframes with inequality conditions

Tags: python-polars

I would like to do a join between two dataframes, using as join condition an inequality condition, i.e. *greater than*.

Given two dataframes, I would like to get the result equivalent to the SQL written below.

```py
stock_market_value = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 2, 1), date(2022, 3, 1)],
        "price": [10.00, 12.00, 14.00]

    }
)

my_stock_orders = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [date(2022, 1, 15), date(2022, 2, 15)],
        "quantity": [2, 5] 
    }
)
```

I have read that Polars supports join of type asof, but I don't think it applies to my case (maybe putting tolerance equal to infinity?).

For sake of clarity, I wrote the join in form of SQL statement.

```sql
SELECT m.date, m.price * o.quantity AS portfolio_value
FROM stock_market_value m LEFT JOIN my_stock_orders o
  ON m.date >= o.date
```

Example query/output:

```py
duckdb.sql("""
SELECT 
   m.date market_date, 
   o.date order_date, 
   price,
   quantity, 
   price * quantity AS portfolio_value
FROM stock_market_value m LEFT JOIN my_stock_orders o
  ON m.date >= o.date
""").pl()
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────────────┬────────────┬───────┬──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ market_date | order_date | price | quantity | portfolio_value │
│ ---         | ---        | ---   | ---      | ---             │
│ date        | date       | f64   | i64      | f64             │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01  | null       | 10.0  | null     | null            │
│ 2022-02-01  | 2022-01-15 | 12.0  | 2        | 24.0            │
│ 2022-03-01  | 2022-01-15 | 14.0  | 2        | 28.0            │
│ 2022-03-01  | 2022-02-15 | 14.0  | 5        | 70.0            │
└─────────────┴────────────┴───────┴──────────┴─────────────────┘
```

#### Why asof() is not the solution

Comments were suggesting to use asof, but it actually does not work in the way I expect.

##### Forward asof

```py
result_fwd = stock_market_value.join_asof(
    my_stock_orders, left_on="date", right_on="date", strategy="forward"
)

print(result_fwd)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ date       ┆ price ┆ quantity │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ date       ┆ f64   ┆ i64      │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10.0  ┆ 2        │
│ 2022-02-01 ┆ 12.0  ┆ 5        │
│ 2022-03-01 ┆ 14.0  ┆ null     │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

##### Backward asof

```py
result_bwd = stock_market_value.join_asof(
    my_stock_orders, left_on="date", right_on="date", strategy="backward"
)

print(result_bwd)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ date       ┆ price ┆ quantity │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ date       ┆ f64   ┆ i64      │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10.0  ┆ null     │
│ 2022-02-01 ┆ 12.0  ┆ 2        │
│ 2022-03-01 ┆ 14.0  ┆ 5        │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've added an example SQL query and the output to clarify what exactly you're trying to match. Hope that's okay.

Comment: @jqurious thanks, that's exactly the expected result. I took the liberty of rearranging your table rows by date_market and date_order in favor of readability.

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4207#issuecomment-1200906506 is the last relevant reply I could find on the topic of non-equi joins. I'm not sure if anything has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join_asof` to determine which records to exclude from the date logic, then perform a cartesian product + filter yourself on the remainder, then merge everything back together. The following implements what you want, although it's a little bit hacky.

*Update*: Using polars' native cross-product instead of self-defined cartesian product function.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col
from datetime import date


stock_market_value = pl.DataFrame({
    "market_date": [date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 2, 1), date(2022, 3, 1)],
    "price": [10.00, 12.00, 14.00]
})

stock_market_orders = pl.DataFrame({
    "order_date": [date(2022, 1, 15), date(2022, 2, 15)],
    "quantity": [2, 5]
})

# use a backwards join-asof to find rows in market_value that have no rows in orders with order date < market date
stock_market_value = stock_market_value.with_columns(
        stock_market_value.join_asof(
        stock_market_orders,
        left_on="market_date",
        right_on="order_date",
    )["order_date"].is_not_null().alias("has_match")
)
nonmatched_rows = stock_market_value.filter(col("has_match")==False).drop("has_match")

# keep all other rows and perform a cartesian product
matched_rows = stock_market_value.filter(col("has_match")==True).drop("has_match")
df = matched_rows.join(stock_market_orders, how="cross")

# filter based on our join condition
df = df.filter(col("market_date") > col("order_date"))

# concatenate the unmatched with the filtered result for our final answer
df = pl.concat((nonmatched_rows, df), how="diagonal")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ market_date ┆ price ┆ order_date ┆ quantity │
│ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ date        ┆ f64   ┆ date       ┆ i64      │
╞═════════════╪═══════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01  ┆ 10.0  ┆ null       ┆ null     │
│ 2022-02-01  ┆ 12.0  ┆ 2022-01-15 ┆ 2        │
│ 2022-03-01  ┆ 14.0  ┆ 2022-01-15 ┆ 2        │
│ 2022-03-01  ┆ 14.0  ┆ 2022-02-15 ┆ 5        │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join_asof. I you want to look forward you should use the `forward` strategy:

```py
stock_market_value.join_asof(
    my_stock_orders,
    on='date',
    strategy='forward',
).with_columns((pl.col("price") * pl.col("quantity")).alias("value"))

┌────────────┬───────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ price ┆ quantity ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ f64   ┆ i64      ┆ f64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10.0  ┆ 2        ┆ 20.0  │
│ 2022-02-01 ┆ 12.0  ┆ 5        ┆ 60.0  │
│ 2022-03-01 ┆ 14.0  ┆ null     ┆ null  │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: The proposed solution produces a different result than expected. @jqurious added an example of the expected output.

The [asof](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/combining_data/joining.html#asof-join) function associates for each element in the left dataframe at most one element in the right dataframe, i.e. the nearest in a given direction (forward or backward).

Instead, I would like to associate more than one right element, i.e., all those with a date less than or equal to that date.

Comment: In that case you can just flip the join_asof (join my_stock_orders on stock_market_value with `strategy="backaward"`)

Comment: I cannot just flip the direction. I edited the original post to add two examples showing why asof does not work as expected.

Comment: I suggested also flipping stock_market_value and my_stock_orders

Comment: That's not gonna work :) The point is that asof() do a one row to one row join, and I need a one to many.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a general solution or not:

```
stock_market_value = stock_market_value.lazy()
my_stock_orders = my_stock_orders.select('quantity', order_date = 'date').lazy()

slices = (
   stock_market_value
     .with_context(my_stock_orders)
     .with_columns(start = 0)
     .with_columns(
        market_date = 'date',
        idx = pl.arange('start', pl.col('order_date').search_sorted('date', side='right'))
      )
      .explode('idx')
)

(
   my_stock_orders.with_context(slices)
     .select(
        'market_date', 'price', pl.col('order_date', 'quantity').take('idx')
     )
     .with_columns(
        portfolio_value = pl.col('price') * pl.col('quantity')
     )
     .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ market_date ┆ price ┆ order_date ┆ quantity ┆ portfolio_value │
│ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ date        ┆ f64   ┆ date       ┆ i64      ┆ f64             │
╞═════════════╪═══════╪════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01  ┆ 10.0  ┆ null       ┆ null     ┆ null            │
│ 2022-02-01  ┆ 12.0  ┆ 2022-01-15 ┆ 2        ┆ 24.0            │
│ 2022-03-01  ┆ 14.0  ┆ 2022-01-15 ┆ 2        ┆ 28.0            │
│ 2022-03-01  ┆ 14.0  ┆ 2022-02-15 ┆ 5        ┆ 70.0            │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┘
```