# Join with multiples gte / lte conditions in Polars

Tags: python-polars

In spark (PySpark) we have a feature that allow us to make joins like this:

```
delays = delays.join(promises, [
    delays.delay >= promises.mindelay,
    delays.delay <= promises.maxdelay,
], "left")
```

How can I perform this join in Polars?
My both data frames are 30gb+, do Cartesian products and filter after it is impossible :(

Edit (providing examples):
dataframe promise

```
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ maxdelay ┆ mindelay ┆ ref │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ str │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a   │
│ 15       ┆ 5        ┆ b   │
│ 20       ┆ 10       ┆ c   │
│ 25       ┆ 25       ┆ d   │
│ 38       ┆ 25       ┆ e   │
│ 35       ┆ 25       ┆ f   │
│ 40       ┆ 30       ┆ g   │
└──────────┴──────────┴─────┘
```

dataframe delays:

```
┌─────┬───────┐
│ ex  ┆ delay │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ 11    │
│ b   ┆ 24    │
│ c   ┆ 88    │
│ d   ┆ 3     │
│ e   ┆ 32    │
│ f   ┆ 44    │
│ g   ┆ 2     │
└─────┴───────┘
```

expected_output df:

```
┌─────┬───────┬──────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ ex  ┆ delay ┆ ref  ┆ maxdelay ┆ mindelay │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ str  ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ a   ┆ 11    ┆ b    ┆ 15       ┆ 5        │
│ b   ┆ 24    ┆ null ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ c   ┆ 88    ┆ null ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ d   ┆ 3     ┆ a    ┆ 10       ┆ 0        │
│ e   ┆ 32    ┆ e    ┆ 38       ┆ 25       │#note that col "ref"==f could be also, but "e" comes first
│ f   ┆ 44    ┆ null ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ g   ┆ 2     ┆ a    ┆ 10       ┆ 0        │
└─────┴───────┴──────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Because I do a left join, this works like it's look the first match row from the promise dataframe that delays.delay are between the promises.mindelay and promises.maxdelay columns

Comment: Depending on the data/problem you may be able to use `.join_asof` / `.search_sorted` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75399353/join-between-polars-dataframes-with-inequality-conditions but yeah, non-equi joins are not supported directly as of yet. There are quite a few issues about it on the tracker if interested. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10068

Comment: What does that syntax mean? Pretend like everyone, like me, doesn't use spark.

Comment: Spark (with PySpark) offer to you the possibility to pass custom conditions to join, in this example, the join is make where delays.delay is grater or equal to promisses.mindelay and lower than or equal to promisses.maxdelay. As I did a left join, it will always return the first matching row in the promisses df if more than one was founded

Comment: These kinds of joins are better known as Non-equi join

Comment: I think @DeanMacGregor may have also been suggesting to show a small runnable example with input / expected output - Depending on the exact task, there may be ways to emulate the "non-equi join" behaviour to come up with the end result.

Comment: Ahh, srr. I will provide now

Comment: Examples posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a direct way to do this. The only non-equi join in polars is the `join_asof` and it seeks the closest value without going under (or over depending on strategy setting). This is in contrast to the behavior you're looking for which is to take the first row that satisfies the match. Unfortunately it is an inner join only (not a left join) so you'll need to do an extra step to add back the missing rows.

## Step by step

### Step 1

You can get the same effect you're looking for by first augmenting your promise df so that all of the rows have mutually exclusive ranges.
You can do that like this:

```
augpromise=(promise.with_columns(
    augmin=pl.max_horizontal(
        pl.col('mindelay'), 
        pl.col('maxdelay').cummax().shift()+1 #This assumes integers, 
                                              #if other datatype then change +1
        )
    )
.filter(pl.col('maxdelay')>pl.col('augmin'))
.sort('augmin') )
print(augpromise)
shape: (5, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────┬────────┐
│ maxdelay ┆ mindelay ┆ ref ┆ augmin │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ str ┆ i64    │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a   ┆ 0      │
│ 15       ┆ 5        ┆ b   ┆ 11     │
│ 20       ┆ 10       ┆ c   ┆ 16     │
│ 38       ┆ 25       ┆ e   ┆ 26     │
│ 40       ┆ 30       ┆ g   ┆ 39     │
└──────────┴──────────┴─────┴────────┘
```

### Step 2

With that you can do the `join_asof`

```
init_join=(   
    delays.sort('delay')
    .join_asof(augpromise,
        left_on='delay', right_on='augmin')
    .filter(pl.col('delay')<pl.col('maxdelay'))
    .drop('augmin'))
print(init_join)
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ ex  ┆ delay ┆ maxdelay ┆ mindelay ┆ ref │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ str │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ g   ┆ 2     ┆ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a   │
│ d   ┆ 3     ┆ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a   │
│ a   ┆ 11    ┆ 15       ┆ 5        ┆ b   │
│ e   ┆ 32    ┆ 38       ┆ 25       ┆ e   │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────┘
```

### Step 3

As I said before, a `join_asof` is always an inner join so if you want the original rows that had no match you'll need to do an anti join (or filter) and concat them back.

```
pl.concat([
    init_join,
    delays.join(init_join, on='ex', how='anti')
    # delays.filter(~pl.col('ex').is_in(init_join['ex']))
], how='diagonal').sort('ex')
shape: (7, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ ex  ┆ delay ┆ maxdelay ┆ mindelay ┆ ref  │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 11    ┆ 15       ┆ 5        ┆ b    │
│ b   ┆ 24    ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ c   ┆ 88    ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ d   ┆ 3     ┆ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a    │
│ e   ┆ 32    ┆ 38       ┆ 25       ┆ e    │
│ f   ┆ 44    ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ g   ┆ 2     ┆ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a    │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

## Same as above but everything in one call

```
(   
    delays.sort('delay')
    .join_asof(
        promise.with_columns(
            augmin=pl.max_horizontal(
                pl.col('mindelay'), 
                pl.col('maxdelay').cummax().shift()+1
                )
            )
        .filter(pl.col('maxdelay')>pl.col('augmin'))
        .sort('augmin'), 
        left_on='delay', right_on='augmin')
    .filter(pl.col('delay')<pl.col('maxdelay'))
    .drop('augmin')
    .pipe(lambda df: (
        pl.concat([
            df,
            delays.join(df, on='ex', how='anti')
        ], how='diagonal')
    ))
    .sort('ex')
    )
shape: (7, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ ex  ┆ delay ┆ maxdelay ┆ mindelay ┆ ref  │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 11    ┆ 15       ┆ 5        ┆ b    │
│ b   ┆ 24    ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ c   ┆ 88    ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ d   ┆ 3     ┆ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a    │
│ e   ┆ 32    ┆ 38       ┆ 25       ┆ e    │
│ f   ┆ 44    ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ g   ┆ 2     ┆ 10       ┆ 0        ┆ a    │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────┘
```